# ADT rev20 - apps don't install on any AVD

Tags: android, adt

I updated ADT to Rev. 20, and somehow my android projects won't install on any emulator. I created new one - and still staying at "Installing ..." infinitely. How do I revert to old revision or maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Is the emulator running?  Which image are you using?  Do you have a generated .apk in the bin/ folder of the project?  If you manually adb install -r that file, does it work?

Comment: actually, seems it was an eclipse bug.. It installed only some part of all ADT updates. Emulator was running but nothing was going to install. As I reinstalled all updates, it works.